# Install Gvim after vim

Tags: vim, x11, gvim

I would like to run vim via X11 (over SSH). Vim comes pre-installed on my NAS (running Debian), however the GUI is not.

When I run `vim -g`, I get this error:

```
E25: GUI cannot be used: Not enabled at compile time
```

Is there any way to install the GUI by itself, or do I need to reinstall vim altogether?

Comment: Or you can edit files remotely through [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install `apt-get install` either `vim-gtk` or `vim-gnome` or even `vim-lesstif` to get a `vim` gui.

Comment: does it matter which?

Comment: @Jeff Not really; I'd install -gtk if you don't have (and don't want) gnome installed. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/33260/difference-between-vim-gtk-and-vim-gnome